# How to use two ssh daemons on one server using nginx or haproxy

Tags: nginx, ssh, haproxy

First of all, I am new to haproxy and nginx. I would like to know if it is possible to use nginx or haproxy to receive all ssh requests, and forward them to two different ssh deamons based on the domain name. If that is possible which one of the two is the best tool for the job, and how would i configure that tool to do that?

Comment: nginx and haproxy has nothing to do with ssh

Comment: @AlexeyTen: HAProxy at the least is fundamentally a TCP load balancer (that is primarily used for HTTP) and it should be possible to use it to map incoming SSH connections to an array of terminal servers. There is just no information in the SSH protocol for the client to tell the proxy to which specific endpoint it wants to connect.

Comment: Yes, I'm wrong about HAProxy. Actually, I'm wrong about nginx too, since 1.9 also has tcp balancing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SSH protocol doesn't transmit the domain name the client tried to connect to (unlike e.g. HTTP/1.1), so a proxy doesn't have any information to decide how to forward the connection.

Comment: @BenjaminHammerNørgaard the usual solution in this situation (if you're short on IP addresses and can't give each host/daemon its own dedicated IP) is to run `sshd` on alternate ports - 22001, 22002, 22003, etc. - it won't let you select by hostname, but it lets you have multiple connections to different hosts (or daemons) while only using one IP. (Your mileage may vary depending on how permissive intermediate firewalls are).